# getting `Error EROFS: read-only file system, rmdir '/workspace/dist'` error deploying nestjs to google app engine

Tags: node.js, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, nestjs

I would like to deploy a simple NestJS hello-world app to app engine!

- This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "baz",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "node dist/main.js",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.0",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

- This is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
    - name: 'node'
      entrypoint: 'npm'
      args: ['install']
    - name: 'node'
      entrypoint: 'npm'
      args: ['run', 'build']
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: ['build', '--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/hello_npm', '.']
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/hello_npm']
```

- This is the app.yaml

```
  runtime: nodejs18
  environment: flex
```

- And here is my Docker file

```
FROM node:18-alpine 

WORKDIR /hello

COPY package.json /hello/
RUN npm install
COPY . /hello/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am getting an error that says: **Error EROFS: read-only file system, rmdir '/workspace/dist**

After 24 hours debugging and searching on the internet I have no idea what I am doing wrong